# Angular: Retorno de JSON do PHP como Undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

Tenho um componente chamando um serviço que utiliza uma *API* em *PHP* para acessar uma tabela em um banco de dados *MySQL* e retornar as informações no formato JSON.

O *HTML* apresenta corretamente as informações da tabela com o `ngFor´, mas não estou conseguindo utilizar em rotinas do componente, porque está como *"undefined"*.

Quando executo um `console.log(this.objetivos)`, está indicando *"undefined"* e o *Angular* não permite que eu faça uma iteração.

Quando tentei fazer `JSON.parse`, aparece a mensagem

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

**Componente:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ObjetivosService } from './objetivos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-objetivos',
  templateUrl: './objetivos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./objetivos.component.css']
})
export class ObjetivosComponent implements OnInit {

  objetivos;

  objetivosJ;

  constructor(private objetivosService: ObjetivosService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getObjetivos();

  }

  getObjetivos() {

    this.objetivosService.getObjetivos().subscribe(objetivos => { this.objetivos = objetivos });

    console.log(this.objetivos);

    this.objetivosJ = JSON.parse(this.objetivos);

    console.log(this.objetivosJ);

  }

}
```

**Serviço:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ObjetivosService {

  //private data;

  //getData: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getObjetivos() {

    return this.http.get("API/objetivos.php");

  }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<h2>
  Meus Objetivos
</h2>
<div class="collection">
  <a href="#!" class="collection-item"
     *ngFor="let objetivo of objetivos"
     [routerLink]="['/objetivo', objetivo.idobjetivo]">
    ID-Objetivo {{ objetivo.idobjetivo }} Data {{ objetivo.dataobjetivo }} Objetivo {{ objetivo.objetivo }}
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua chamada é assíncrona então coloca os logs e conversões no subscribe

```
this.objetivosService.getObjetivos().subscribe(objetivos => { 
this.objetivos = objetivos;
console.log(this.objetivos);  
 this.objetivosJ = JSON.parse(this.objetivos); 
 console.log(this.objetivosJ);
});
```

Comment: Agora está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (objetivos.component.ts:38)
...

Comment: Parece que o json que seu PHP volta está inválido. Verifique se o conteúdo da resposta é um json válido

Comment: Creio que o JSON retornado pelo PHP é válido pelo fato de o HTML conseguir apresentar corretamente as informações no Browser.

Resposta do PHP:

[{"idobjetivo":"15","idatleta":"83","dataobjetivo":"2018-07-29","objetivo":"Treino base","tpreg":"A"},{"idobjetivo":"21","idatleta":"83","dataobjetivo":"2018-06-10","objetivo":"Treino H2","tpreg":"A"}]